# How I can Recover sorted data in a Grid View using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a GridView with a search textbox and a Search Button, Once I try to search some records by Location, by Name, etc. I have a list of records that shows properly, if I select one record and I decide that is not the one I have and I click a back button that I include , my search is lost and I have to search again.

I understand that I have to create a session to solve this, but I am getting lost. This is what I have so far.  Any idea?

```
 protected void search_button_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
            gvCompanyList.PageIndex = 0;
    SearchForCompanies();

    //Save search criteria into a session
    Session["SearchString"] = tbSearchTerm.Text;
}



protected void gvCompanyList_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow pagerRow = (GridViewRow)gvCompanyList.BottomPagerRow;

    if (pagerRow != null && pagerRow.Visible == false)
        pagerRow.Visible = true;


  // To Call the session

    String searchCriteria;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSearchTerm.Text))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["SearchString"].ToString()))
        {
            searchCriteria = Session["SearchString"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please indicate the exact problem that is occurring.

Comment: I have a Grid view, with a search button, I can sort all my contacts by Location or by company name, lets say by Province "Ontario", once i click search it works, i have all the contacts from Ontario, then I click one but i realize that that one is not the one I am looking for, so I click back and my list is gone, I have to Click Ontario in my search button again to bring back that list. What i want is to click back and have my "Ontario" list there without the need to type the search again

Comment: I understand the scenario, but what is wrong with the code you've posted? Does it not work at all? Does it produce errors? Does it half work?

Comment: In the last IF statement the searchCriteria is underlined  saying that the Name SearchCriteria does not exist in the current context

Comment: That means you haven't declared `searchCriteria` of any type. You need to declare it before you can use it.

Comment: How I should declare the searchCriteria?

Comment: The way you declare any object. `<type> <name>;` such as `String searchCriteria;`

Comment: I declare it as you told me (check my code above), but I still dont have any progress.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are on the right track. You just need to create a button now to execute the search using your session variable if it is clicked.

Comment: Hi Clay
Actualy I do have a Search Button to execute the search, do you notice if I am missing something?



protected void search_button_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //SearchType = 1;
        gvCompanyList.PageIndex = 0;
        SearchForCompanies();

        //Save search criteria into a session
        Session["SearchString"] = tbSearchTerm.Text;
      //  Session["test"] = gvCompanyList;
       // gvCompanyList = null;
    }